# Android crash when I use react-native-webrtc in expo eject to expokit project

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, expo

When I use react-native-webrtc library in expo eject to expokit project, the android app release crash, Instead, using react-native-webrtc library in regular react-native project(not expo) is fine.

I got this error by adb logcat

```
06-21 10:42:44.188 24576 24576 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00000000001e79e8  /data/app/com.tsao-1/lib/arm64/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x1e1000)
06-21 10:42:44.189 24576 24576 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0000000000258dac  /data/app/com.tsao-1/lib/arm64/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x1e1000)
06-21 10:42:44.189 24576 24576 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00000000002566e4  /data/app/com.tsao-1/lib/arm64/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x1e1000)
06-21 10:42:44.189 24576 24576 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000000001e1020  /data/app/com.tsao-1/lib/arm64/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x1e1000) (JNI_OnLoad+32)
```

This is library link
https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc#creator

I know it is less information, but I really have no idea about what is happening, anyone have some experience in this library or any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I find regular react-native project setting minifyEnabled = false, but expo setting true, finally I also changed minifyEnabled setting to false in expo project, then it work.

```
release {
  minifyEnabled false // setting true will crash
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/646

Comment: I don't know real crash reason, but I guess setting minifyEnabled = true may cause some library conflict sometimes